# Formula to Add 1 to current cell if certain text is picked detected in a range of cells

Tags: excel

I am currently making a spreadsheet which has information relating to properties, One of the columns lists the source for the property such as Zoopla, Rightmove, Fish4. I need a formula that will scan the entire Sources Column for 1 word and add a value to a cell that shows the total number of Sourced information from that source. I have been trying for sometime and cannot figure out the formula.

Rightmove Total = 3
Zoopla Total = 4

Any information is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
=SUM(IF((A1:A5="Saint"),1,0))
```

if the searched string is found, **assign 1** to each `true` condition. then `add` up the results and there you go!

**Note:** please change the column numbers and search string, as this is just an example

Comment: Thanks, Having difficulty getting it to Sum up the numbers, the Cell always displays "1" even it should display 7. Probably me doing something wrong!

Comment: I had to use semicolon ; instead of comma ,

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem properly, what you need is the `COUNTIF()` function.

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A, Sheet2!A2)
```

Will count the number of occurrences of the value within cell `A2` of `Sheet2`, into column `A:A` of `Sheet1`.

So, if `Sheet2!A2` has `Rightmove` and `Rightmove` appears three times in `Sheet1!A:A`, then the formula will return `3`.